# Is there any third charge in paper or is it neutral?

Tags: electrostatics, charge

To help understand my question consider this example. I took two rods which were oppositely charged I placed them both never some small pieces of paper both the rods were attracting paper pieces so I wanted to know if there is any third charge in paper.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no third charge, but there is **electrostatic induction**, i.e. a redistribution of electric charge in an object that is caused by the influence of nearby charges.

Pieces of paper are approximately electrically neutral, i.e. **not net charge** in them, but the influence of charged rods influence the distribution of charges on in, attracting opposite and repelling equal-sign charges. Since the distance between the opposite charges is smaller than the distance between the equal-sign charges, you get an attractive force, whatever the nature of the extra charges on the rod is.

Since paper is not a good conductor, or better it's a **dielectric**, you should not think at macroscopic displacement of free charges (as it would be in metals and other good conductors), but small displacement, **polarization**, at microscopic level.

Have a look here, at the first lesson of prof. Lewin's course at the MIT about classical electromagnetism: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1-SibwIPM4